# apacite package causes misaligned footnotes in Springer document (svjour3)

Tags: margins, footnotes

I'm having trouble with footnotes and the *apacite* package. I'm using the Springer documentclass *svjour3* and XeLaTeX (but I have the same problem with PDFLaTeX). Whenever I include the *apacite* package it leads to the first line of the footnote to be way too far over the left margin edge (see image). This does not happen if the documentclass is *article*. How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{me}
\institute{me \at university}
\date{}
\maketitle

Some text. \footnote{This footnote looks wrong.}

\end{document}
```

[image: The footnote is not where it should be.]

Apologies if this question has already been asked and answered. I tried looking for similar questions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svjour3` class redefines some footnote related macros to use `\bibindent` in some places, and `apacite` sets it to `-2.5em`.

I'm not sure Springer likes `apacite`, but perhaps you can do it by resetting `\bibindent` just before the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

\edef\svjourbibindent{\the\bibindent}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\edef\apacitebibindent{\the\bibindent}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\bibindent}{\svjourbibindent}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{\setlength{\bibindent}{\apacitebibindent}}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author{me}
\institute{me \at university}
\date{}
\maketitle

Some text. \footnote{This footnote looks right.}

\end{document}
```

If you add an example of bibliographic item, I can check for the typesetting of the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the issue. I might end up going for a different citation style after all, but this works great.